# new A() vs. static new A()

Tags: java

What is the difference from

```
class Test {
    A a = new A();
}
```

to

```
class Test {
   static A a = new A();
}
```

Does the virtual machine perform differently in the initialization?

Comment: Also see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first class there will be a member variable for each instance of the class Test. In the Second class there will be just one member variable for the whole class Test.